# Lubuntu - Is it possible to install network-manager from an boot disk

Tags: lubuntu, network-manager

I did a a stupid mistake by uninstalling network manager and nm tray. Is it possible to boot into the same type of installation disk and install network manager and nm tray without ethernet.

Or does anyone know where a deb package for it is with all its dependicies

Comment: How do u connect to the internet. Do u use wifi?

Comment: Yes i do actaully, i dont have access to a actaul router so i use my hotspot

Answer (score 0):

you could use the wpa_supplicant package that comes by default on lubuntu to connect to the wifi hotspot and once internet is flowing you can then install network-manager. I assume your hotspot does not have a password on it.

First of all kill wpa_supplicant:

```
sudo killall wpa_supplicant
```

then create the wpa_supplicant file:

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

and paste in the network specs:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant

#settings for connecting to an open hotspot without password
network={
    ssid="HOTSPOT NAME"
    key_mgmt=NONE
}
```

replace HOTSPOT NAME with the name of your hotspot

now start wpa_supplicant via that conf file:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -iwlp2s0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

wlp2s0 is the name of your wifi interface. you can find it with `iw dev`

after your machine is able to successful connect to the hotspot request for an ip address:

```
sudo dhclient -r
sudo dhclient wlp2s0
```

ping to check if internet is working:

```
ping google.com
```

Now if you were able to get the internet to work you can then install network-manager:

```
sudo apt install network-manager
```

Hope this helps

Comment: When i tried to connect by the wpa_supplicant -wlo1... It just popped up the help menu

Comment: Ok it is now working except that it is saying "temporary failure in name resolution" for pinging google

Comment: do `echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf` and try again to use google's dns